# How can we recover/restore lost/overwritten data in our Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012?

Tags: backup, data-recovery, sql-server, restore, sql

I was going to restore our old backup of our data using SQL. I right clicked on the Databases > restore databases > Device > ok.

Here I did not change the name under Destination (for Database) and apparently it has overwritten the existent data at the software.

I did not make any backup from the existing files before restoring the old backup data.

Is there any way to restore the existed data again?
from what I can see at the (object explorer panel) under SQL server Logs, there are some Archives. Is there any way to restore the data using that?

I also checked the other solutions like restoring from AdventureWorks but I do not have such a file.

[image: enter image description here]]

Comment: If you overwrite data in a SQL table the data cannot be recovered.  I assume you selected a backup set when you performed this action?

Comment: @CaldeiraG : yes I selected our old backup. I can not use those Archives listed in the SQL server logs to read back the data again?

Comment: @user6661080 hey, you mentioned me instead of Ramhound :) i just edited your question.

Comment: @Ramhound:  yes I selected our old backup. I can not use those Archives listed in the SQL server logs to read back the data again?

Comment: You cannot use a log archive to restore your data.  You would have to select a backup set (which you indicate does not exist)